# ProcessPoolExecutor: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending

Tags: python, django, multithreading, multiprocessing

Background:
Python 3.6.5, Django 1.10
I am trying to reduce the response times using ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor to speed up my APIs. Adding sample code:

```
from django import db
db.connections.close_all()
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    executors_list.append(
        executor.submit(self.get_investment_data_table, current=current)
    )
    executors_list.append(
        executor.submit(self.get_scheme_wise_cashflow_sum, current=current)
    )
    executors_list.append(
        executor.submit(self.get_scheme_wise_xirr, current=current)
    )
    executors_list.append(executor.submit(self.scheme_wise_transactions))

executors_list = list(executors_list)

all_investment_list = executors_list[0].result()
scheme_wise_cashflow_sum = executors_list[1].result()
scheme_wise_xirr = executors_list[2].result()
transactions = executors_list[3].result()
# club all 4 and return as response
```

Issue:
While trying out ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor for different functions, I found that Threadpool is working fine but when I am trying ProcessPoolExecutor, I am getting this error:

`concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.`

The weird thing is that **the api call succeeds for 2-3 times and after that it starts failing continuously**. The response size is around 5 MB. All the underlying functions contain db call and at least some amount of processing. What I am confused about is that if it was a pickling error, the code should be failing from the first time.

Can somebody help me out or point me in the right direction as to how to debug and fix the issue.

Comment: I had to reinstall python to get the issue fixed. Not sure what had caused the issue.